# jquery Slidebar not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

Could anyone eplain to me, why this isn't working in IE?
It's fading perfectly into each image in other browsers, but when executed in IE, it only shows the last image(image 5) and stays that way.
And maybe come up with a possible solution ? I am very new to jquery
JS:

```
var rotationTime = 3000;
var fadeTimer = 500;
var zStart = 25;

var totalBanners;
var currentImage = 1;

$(document).ready(function(){
    totalBanners = $('#fade-slider > div').length;
    for(i=1;i<=totalBanners;i++){
        $('#img-' + i).css('z-index', '' + (zStart-i) + '');
    }
    $(document).everyTime(rotationTime,  'imagefader', function(){          
        if(currentImage < totalBanners){
            $('#img-' + currentImage).animate({opacity: 0}, fadeTimer);
            currentImage += 1;
        }
        else{
            currentImage = 1;
            $('#img-' + currentImage).animate({opacity: 1}, fadeTimer, 'linear', function(){
                for(i=1;i<=totalBanners;i++){
                    $('#img-' + i).animate({opacity: 1}, 0);
                }
            });         
        }       
    }, 0);
});
```

CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
    #fade-slider {
      width:570px;
      height:207px;
      overflow:hidden;
      margin:0px;
      padding:0px;
      position:relative;
    }

    .position-zero {
        position:absolute;
        top:0px;
        left:0px;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="fade-slider">
                        <div id="img-1" class="position-zero"><a href="#"><img src="images/slider/image-1.jpg" alt="Image1" /></a></div>
                        <div id="img-2" class="position-zero"><a href="#"><img src="images/slider/image-2.jpg" alt="Image2" /></a></div>  
                        <div id="img-3" class="position-zero"><a href="#"><img src="images/slider/image-3.jpg" alt="Image3" /></a></div>    
                        <div id="img-4" class="position-zero"><a href="#"><img src="images/slider/image-4.jpg" alt="Image4" /></a></div>     
                        <div id="img-5" class="position-zero"><a href="#"><img src="images/slider/image-5.jpg" alt="Image5" /></a></div>       
                    </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean with *not working in IE*? Do you get any errors? The effect is not what you want? And could you post the complete code (we don't have your HTML), or maybe a jsfiddle or link to your site?

Comment: Hi Oriol, i updated the code with my CSS and HTML for this script.
It's fading perfectly into each image in other browsers, but when executed in IE, it only shows the last image(image 5) and stays that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're taling about IE8 - when mentioning IE ...

```
opacity
```

will not work properly in IE8 , try something like this

```
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
```

that last part 'Opacity=50' would equal `opacity: .5` just adjust accordingly

for IE5- IE7 try this

```
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
```

Comment: Ohh i see, i've read about the opacity problems.
How can i integrate thoose into this script?